# PHP Form Post and Insert into multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

I'm stumped.  I've looked this up on multiple answers on Stackoverflow, but just can't get it.  Maybe I'm just not seeing something.

I'm making a Family Feud game and using PHP and MySQL databases to store and retrieve information.  For the Fast Money Round, I have a database with a Table called "FastMoney1" I'm using an HTML5 form and PHP to post the data in the form to that table, which has two columns: answer and score

I'm running my query through a for loop, but it's not posting anything to the table.  I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question1answer" name="answer[0]" placeholder="Question 1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="question1score" name="score[0]" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question1answer" name="answer[1]" placeholder="Question 2">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="question1score" name="score[1]" placeholder="0">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4" align="center">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        require "config.php";

        for ($i = 0; $i<count($_POST); $i++){
            $answer = $_POST['answer'][$i];
            $score = $_POST['score'][$i];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `fastMoney1`(`answer`, `score`) VALUES ('$answer','$score')";
            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "";
            } else {
                echo $conn->error;
            }
        }

        $conn->close();
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";

    }

?>
```

All of this lives on the same PHP page, which is why I do not have an action attached to the form.

The config.php is an include that calls the host, username, password and database and opens the connection

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, I am not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that PHP variables as case sensitive you have given name `Submit`  in form while in php you are checking `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` which never become true.
 change it to

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){ //<----- S in upper case
```

**EDIT**
You also need to change your loop to

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($_POST['answer']); $i++){
```

Comment: I actually have a total of 6 pairs of fields, answer and score - but the submit is only posting the first three to the database, not all six.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" />
```

i changed

```
 name="Submit"
```

to

```
 name="submit"
```

"Submit" to "submit"  ----->"S" to "s"

and it works fine

Comment: I stated why in the issue.  because I have the isset($_POST['submit']) AND the php and html live on the same page

Answer (score -1):

see your sql statement you don't need those ampersand in table name and column names INSERT INTO `fastMoney1`(`answer`, `score`) VALUES ('$answer','$score')